# Jaxb2Marshaller cannot unmarshal non XmlRoot Elements in a thread safe way

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, jaxb

I have a bunch of classes generated from a schema. I cannot touch them - immutable source for me.

These classes are top-level elements in the schema. Each is pointing to a type of the same name:

```
    <xsd:element name="Foo" type="FooType"/>
```

One class is generated `FooType` with all neccessary attributes, but it has no `@XmlRoot` annotation. A class `Foo` is not generated.

In JAXB, the implementation uses a lookup table and explicitely unmarshals the object:

```
JAXBContext ctx ...
FooType x = ctx.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(source, FooType.class);
```

In spring-boot, using `Jaxb2Marshaller`, I cannot give the class-Parameter. There it seems, that the marshalling relies only on the `@XmlRoot` annotation to do it's magic. 
When setting the `marshaller.setMappedClass(FooType.class)`, the springboot unmarshaller will use it - but then, this is set once in the instance and not thread safe, only if I create the Jaxb2Marshaller on demand (seems expensive).

I would need access to the JAXBContext itself, to create my own unmarshaller. While this is possible, I don't get the magic initialization on the unmarshaller. The useful method `Jaxb2Marshaller#createUnmarshaller()` is `protected`.

I only see a solution in extending the `Jaxb2Marshaller` to my own dummy object to widen access to the protected methods. This seems unclean.

I would rather drop the `Jaxb2Marshaller` completely and go down the way of the legacy app and use JAXB directly. Spring's JAXB seems not to be intended to cover my case here.

Questions: Did I missunderstand the concept? What is the intended use of `Jaxb2Marshaller.setMappedClass()`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not completely address the heart of your issue, but if the lack of @XmlRootElement is your problem, I propose for you to slightly adjust your schema.

I assume you have something like this:

```
<xsd:element name="Foo" type="FooType"/>

<!-- and somewhere in the schema also have -->
<xsd:complexType name="FooType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="blah" type="BlahType"/>
        <xsd:element name="blah-blah" type="BlahBlahType" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

What you need to do is remove the two specified above and replace with:

```
<xsd:element name="Foo">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="blah" type="BlahType"/>
            <xsd:element name="blah-blah" type="BlahBlahType" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

When you will generate your classes along with Foo which will automatically have the @RootXmlElement

Comment: Sorry, this does not address the issue, schema and generated classes are immutable for me. I could do changes via xjb, as long as the resulting code produces the same xml, though - but this is extremely delicate.

Comment: ok no problem, just to mention that you don't really change the schema, your xsd is not structured "properly" to generate the root annotation. The structure of the classes do not change. I would suggest that you try it just to see what happens

Comment: The schema is a delivered data structure from a public organisation. It already exists in 5-6 versions and while I can change this file I will not do it just to overcome a shortcoming in the access modifiers in Jaxb2Marshaller :-)